# How to query a many-to-many collection with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I've been trying to interpret the answers to similar questions but haven't been able to make it work.

I have a list of activities, and each activity as a list of participants. Here are the mappings:

```
  <class name="Activity" lazy="false">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <list name="Participants">
      <key column="Activity" />
      <index column="Ord" />
      <many-to-many column="Contact" class="Model.Contact" />
    </list>
    <property name="Timestamp" />
  </class>

  <class name="Contact" lazy="false">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
  </class>
```

I am currently retrieving the activities ten at a time with this criteria:

```
var crit = ModelSession.Current.CreateCriteria<Activity>()
   .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Timestamp"))
   .SetFirstResult(start)
   .SetMaxResults(count);
```

Now I need to retrieve only those activities in which a particular person participated, in other words: where Contact.Name like '%some_name%'. In raw SQL I'd probably write something like this:

```
select * from Activity where ID in (select p.Activity from Participants p, 
Contact c where p.Contact=c.ID and c.Name like '%some_name%')
```

Any idea how to do this, with HQL or ICriteria, in a way that lets me keep the paged results and ordering? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ChssPly76 response above wasn't quite correct — this is a unidirectional relationship, so there is no "activity" property on the contacts to project — but it got me on the right track. 
The correct answer is actually much simpler (in its own answer so I can format it properly):

```
crit.CreateCriteria("Participants")
   .Add(Expression.Like("Name", like));
```

Added to the criteria from the original question, this says "return a page of activities, ordered by timestamp, where a participant has this name".

Taken a step further, I really wanted any activity where the search term appeared in the list of participants OR in the description of the activity. In this case you really do need the subquery.

```
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<Activity>()
   .SetProjection(Projections.Property("ID"))
   .CreateCriteria("Participants")
   .Add(Expression.Like("Name", search_term));

crit.Add(Expression.Or(
   Subqueries.PropertyIn("ID", subquery),
   Expression.Like("Description", search_term));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an appropriate condition to your criteria:

```
crit.CreateAlias("Participants", "participant")
.Add( Expression.Like("participant.Name", "%some_name%") );
```

See [Criteria associations](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations) chapter of NHibernate documentation for more details

**Update** You can use [DetachedCriteria](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries) to specify your **Participant** conditions as a subquery:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Participant))
 .SetProjection(Projections.Property("activity"))
 .Add( Expression.Like("name", "%some_name%") );
crit.add( Subqueries.GeAll("ID", subquery) ).List();
```

Comment: I could have sworn when I tried CreateAlias() last night I was getting duplicate records back, but no matter this worked a treat. Thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: No, this is still breaking. If I have an activity with three participants, it will appear three times (once for each participant) in the result set. So the join is duplicating the records for each pairing.

Comment: That wasn't quite it, but you got me on the right track (see answer below). Thanks!